# How to script a stored procedure from TSQL

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I know there's a way to do this as I've seen it done - I just can't remember how.

I want to run a SQL command which will return the script to create the stored procedure as a result.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using sp_helptext command :

```
sp_helptext 'yourprocname'
```

or using object_definition :

```
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID('yourprocname'))
```

Comment: @Martin Smith : You also edited your answer and added EXEC sp_helptext 'your_schema.your_procname' line after my answer. So it means it also copied ?

Comment: @MartinSmith : yes, I copied last line from your answer cause no need to type it again. But that doesn't mean you only know that answer and not your private. :)

Comment: @MartinSmith : Btw your first answer not giving result in readable format. it gives in one line.

Comment: @MartinSmith : If you use option 'result to text' then it will cut down SP text. So you have only one option remaining is 'result to file'. My first answer will work in all options :)

Comment: @MartinSmith : If OP want it in programing not in SSMS then why he accepted answer :)

Comment: OP doesn't mentioned anywhere that he need in programtically. If I am an idiot then OP also idiot and you also :)

Comment: @UpendraChaudhari - Your last point is correct. No idea why I got so wound up!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID('your_schema.your_procname'))
```

or

```
EXEC sp_helptext 'your_schema.your_procname'
```

Comment: I did not see any editing so I will award answer to the first response however I will mark both as useful.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server Management Studio, right-click the proc in the Object Explorer window and choose **Script Stored Procedure as** ...then choose the operation (Create, Drop, etc.) you want to script.

Comment: True enough, I did read it as "how to script a TSQL stored procedure"!