# Use sqlcmd utility to generate stored procedures lists

Tags: sql-server, list, sqlcmd

I know we can do this by going Tasks > Generate Scripts > Stored Procedure.

Is there a way to do it using sqlcmd?
I'm planning to write a batch file to automate it.

Comment: You can do this with SSDT. Which can also validate, version and deploy your schema and changes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I automate the "generate scripts" task in SQL Server Management Studio 2008?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483568/how-can-i-automate-the-generate-scripts-task-in-sql-server-management-studio-2)

Comment: This may help also. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567530/how-to-script-a-stored-procedure-from-tsql

Answer (score 1):

You could combine the system table [sys.procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188737.aspx) and the function [object_definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345443.aspx).

```
-- Return the name and definition of first three SPs in the current db.
SELECT TOP 3
    Name,
    OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) AS SQLStatement
FROM
    sys.procedures
ORDER BY
    Name
;
```

Word of warning; If a procedure is renamed using [sp_rename](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188351.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), the old definition is returned.  This is a [closed bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/398203/sp-rename-doesnt-change-the-text-of-udfs-or-procs-sp-helptext-then-returns-a-script-with-the-old-name) on connect.